# Azure sql database node.js which module to use?

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm confused which node module is to use for azure sql database connection. While searching how to connect to azure sql databse by node.js. I found msnodesql and node-sqlserver. Even I saw statement as msnodesql (formerly node-sqlserver). So is node-sqlserver depreciated? Now it is called msnodesql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see when installing it via NPM *node-sqlserver* is superseded by [msnodesql](https://npmjs.org/package/msnodesql). The documentation seems to use *node-sqlserver*, but in my opinion you should go with the new one.

Comment: The Azure documentation is often poorly maintained, and they don't revisit old pages to update them when the ecosystem changes outside their own SDKs. And sometimes even within them.